# How can I get information about a potential Vagrant box?

Tags: build, vagrant, development-environment

I need to create a documented, clean and reproducible development environment. I'm climbing the Vagrant learning curve (as used with VirtualBox), and it's the perfect tool for this. To be able to type

```
$ vagrant init ubuntu/trusty64
$ vagrant up
```

and have a VM ready to go is amazing and powerful. I've been crafting a [Vagrantfile](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/vagrantfile/) with all my needed tools, and life seems to be good.

*Except...* there's a big problem. Vagrant is designed to treat the details of what boxes and versions are available, where they come from, what are the differences, etc. as "magic" to be hidden from the user. This is wonderful for the beginning programmer, but in a professional development environment this can be deadly: if a box is unexpectedly updated, or if my coworker gets a different box, the build may break in extremely subtle ways. As an experienced developer, I know that this way lies madness.

I know about the Hashicorp [Vagrant atlas](https://atlas.hashicorp.com/boxes/search), but that still just lists versions on enormous web pages, with no information on what the differences are. I also know about the hack of taking an Atlas URL and adding a `.json` suffix, e.g....

- web page describing box: https://atlas.hashicorp.com/ubuntu/boxes/trusty64
- JSON describing box: https://atlas.hashicorp.com/ubuntu/boxes/trusty64.json

... but this is a [kludge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kludge#Computer_science) at best, as it's a pain in the rear to track this down, the JSON format isn't made for people to interpret, and there's still no information on just what changes from version to version.

I even fired up [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) to watch Vagrant's traffic when downloading ubuntu/trusty64. Much of the traffic was encrypted, but I did find that although the Vagrant CLI printed the box URL as https://atlas.hashicorp.com/ubuntu/boxes/trusty64/versions/20160919.0.1/providers/virtualbox.box, the box was actually being downloaded from http://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/vagrant/trusty/current/trusty-server-cloudimg-amd64-vagrant-disk1.box. And, the header of the box file included a lot of interesting information about just what the box would be emulating (disk partitions, processors, etc. etc. etc.).

Needless to say, I shouldn't have to do this. The Vagrant CLI should provide information about a named, not-yet-downloaded box:

- a description of the box
- a list of available versions
- what a specific version added compared to the previous version
- where a specific version is hosted
- what the configuration of the box will be
- who created it
- etc., etc., etc.,

So, is there an official way to get this sort of information for a named, not-yet-downloaded box?

Comment: I kinda went this road and faced issues _The Vagrant CLI should provide information about a named, not-yet-downloaded box_ I don't think the vagrant CLI would provide that but we could expect that from the box uploaded on atlas and have this documentation there, I know some boxes have that but most not - so at the end I turned to [packer](http://www.packer.io) and built my own boxes, I am using vmware so anyway most of the boxes were for virtual box (even though there is more of other providers nowadays) and it was a good thing - the packer template as well as kickstart file documents the box